# Nav tabs - stack as square buttons rather than 2 lines

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Update**: To anyone who encounters this in the future: In this snippet you can't see the problem I am talking about, but I found out the cause for the problem: in the original code I have another nav - the main navbar, which had `display:block`, that caused the issue

I am using nav tabs so that you can choose between 2 pages from a single page:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      
      
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#" style="color:white;background-color:blue">First Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Second Link</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

It looks alright on web, but when viewing from a mobile, the 2 navs stack on top of a each other and fill the entire width of the screen.
What I'm trying to achieve is that they look like 2 square buttons at the same line, like so:

```
-------------------
|  First | Second |
|  Link  |  Link  |   
-------------------
```

*Edit: From some reason they don't stack as 2 lines in this snippet, on my smartphone they do, same code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `br` tag

CSS:

```
.nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link br{
   display: none;
}
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 600px){
   .nav-tabs .nav-item .nav-link br{
       display: block;
   }
}
```

[enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
        <li class="nav-item text-center">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#" style="color:white;background-color:blue">First <br> Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item text-center">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Second <br> Link</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it to break line only on mobile view, from some reason I can't replicate the error in my snippet

Comment: @pileup Add some css then check :)

Comment: You were right. Actually, the  nav inherited `display:block` from the main navbar, causing this to not perform as intented

Answer (score 0):

Its because bootstrap defined `flex-wrap: wrap` in your `.nav` css, thats why tabs are going to the next line when the text width is greater than the device width.

So try to write a custom class in your nav class and define `flex-wrap: nowrap` css in your nav

```css
.custom.nav {
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center custom">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" href="#" style="color:white;background-color:blue">First Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Second Link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have no idea why here it works, and on my live site I do the same, and still both nav links simple stretch to the entire width and across 2 separate lines

Comment: @pileup make sure that your css is overriding the existing one. Try web inspect tool to check.

Comment: I tried with inline style + important rule, from some reason they stretch the entire width on mobile. The weird thing is that when copy the exact code from my page, and remove every other CSS rules, it still stretched the entire line, I'm trying to find out why

Comment: @pileup try to make a fiddle with your complete code to resolve the issue. https://fiddle.jshell.net/

Comment: Ok I realized that including the bootstrap navbar (via PHP) is causing this problem. Now have to find out which rule is doing it. Because nowrap did not help, even when I did `!important`. Both of them inherit same CSS rules regarding flex, so not the problem

Comment: Found the culprit: it inherited the following rule from the navbar:
`.nav{display: block;}`